# How to use search filtering and category filtering same time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, filter

I hope to make a product filtering by type in search and category filter.

Here is the filter nav:

```
<div id="sortFunction">
  <label id="search">
    <input oninput="w3.filterHTML('#listProductWrapper', '.product', this.value);" placeholder="Search Here..." id="querySearch">
  </label>
  <div id="cateListContainer">
    <h2 class="in">Categories</h2>
    <input type="radio" name="cate" id="cateRadioAll" value="all" checked onclick="cateFilter(this.value);">
    <label for="cateRadioAll">All</label>
    <input type="radio" name="cate" id="cateRadioNewBorn" value="newborn" onclick="cateFilter(this.value);">
    <label for="cateRadioNewBorn">New Born</label>
    <input type="radio" name="cate" id="cateRadioValentine" value="valentine" onclick="cateFilter(this.value);">
    <label for="cateRadioValentine">Valentine</label>
    <input type="radio" name="cate" id="cateRadioFlower" value="flower" onclick="cateFilter(this.value);">
    <label for="cateRadioFlower">Flower</label>
    <input type="radio" name="cate" id="cateRadioFestival" value="festival" onclick="cateFilter(this.value);">
    <label for="cateRadioFestival">Festival</label>
    <input type="radio" name="cate" id="cateRadioSales" value="sales" onclick="cateFilter(this.value);">
    <label for="cateRadioSales">Sales</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the product content:

```
<div id="listProductWrapper">
  <div class="product all newborn">
    <div class="productImg" id="productImg01"></div>
    <div class="productName">Pig (Deluxe)</b></div>
    <div class="productPrice">300</div>
  </div>
  <div class="product all newborn sales">
    <div class="productImg" id="productImg02"></div>
    <div class="productName">Pig (Normal)</b></div>
    <div class="productPrice">200</div>
  </div>
  <div class="product all newborn">
    <div class="productImg" id="productImg03"></div>
    <div class="productName">Shoes</div>
    <div class="productPrice">239</div>
  </div>
  <div class="product all flower">
    <div class="productImg" id="productImg04"></div>
    <div class="productName">Flower x14pcs</div>
    <div class="productPrice">9999</div>
  </div>
  <div class="product all valentine flower">
    <div class="productImg" id="productImg05"></div>
    <div class="productName">Valentine Flower</div>
    <div class="productPrice">500</div>
  </div>
  <div class="product all festival sales">
    <div class="productImg" id="productImg06"></div>
    <div class="productName">Limited Edition</div>
    <div class="productPrice">***</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I used w3.js filtering function to filter users type into the search bar. But I modified some codes, so far it is work!

```
w3.filterHTML = function(id, sel, filter) {
  var a, b, c, i, ii, iii, hit;
  a = w3.getElements(id);
  for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    b = w3.getElements(sel);
    for (ii = 0; ii < b.length; ii++) {
      hit = 0;
      if (b[ii].textContent.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter.toUpperCase()) > -1) {
        hit = 1;
      }
      c = b[ii].getElementsByTagName("*");
      for (iii = 0; iii < c.length; iii++) {
        if (c[iii].textContent.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter.toUpperCase()) > -1) {
          hit = 1;
        }
      }
      if (hit == 1) {
        b[ii].style.display = "";
      } else {
        b[ii].style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  }
};
```

Let all products have class `.all`, (`.product` is for css). Radio buttons have the value that related to each category. Normally, if user click the radio button, will run:

```
var cateFilter = function(filter) {
  $(".all").hide();
  $("." + filter).show();
};
```

It is work for no value in the search bar. If the search bar has value, then run this function, the type in search/filtering function will not work. Just can sort by category. But after click the category radio button, users change the input of search, the category and search by type in will work together.

In my case, is how to make the function of when users have already typed in some text for search in search filter, then they also click the radio button of category to filter category, I want the function can work with category filtered and type in search filtered.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: My Idea is here: if ($("#querySearch").val().length > 0) {
  $(".all").hide();
  $("." + filter).show();
  var a = $("#querySearch").val();
  $("#querySearch").val(a);
}
But it not work

Comment: I'm not sure if changing the querySearch value with code triggers the oninput handler.  Did you try calling w3.filterHtml instead?

Comment: Yes, I try to call w3.filterHtml again when onclick radio button. But I found that this two filtering function cannot use at the same time. The latest called function will cover the previous one filtering.